# How can I increase bar text font-size in plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, bar-chart

I am using the the following code to draft a bar chart. The problem is that the text on top of each bar is becoming smaller the more bars and more digits there are. Right now, with 5-digit numbers it is not readable anymore. Would you please be able in helping me increase the bar text size using plotly and without modifying the bars' width?

```
figure = px.bar(
    data_frame = financial_data,
     title="Net Revenue YTD",
     x = "Period",
     y="Net Revenue YTD",
     color="Actual or Plan",
     barmode="group",
     text="Net Revenue YTD",
     labels={"Net Revenue YTD": "Net Revenue YTD (k$)", "Actual or Plan":""},
     color_discrete_map={"Actual": "YellowGreen", "Plan": "darkgreen"},
     width=700
)
figure.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.0f}', textposition='outside')
figure.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=prior_year_data["Period"],
        y=prior_year_data["Net Revenue YTD"],
        name="Last Year",
        opacity=0.5
    )
    
)
figure.show()
```

[Bar Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdelp.jpg)

The only way I found was to increase the bar width, but it is not efficient anymore and makes the chart too big to fit in the ppt where I paste it afterwards.

Comment: [Text and Annotations in Python](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#controlling-text-size-with-uniformtext)